# Associate Xamarin GCM device token with logged in user

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm working my way through a Xamarin tutorial on how to sent push notifications to an Android device [1]. As an example, this works great.

However, I have trouble figuring out how I can associate the device token with a currently logged in user. The tutorial does a pretty basic demonstration on how to obtain a device token and sending this to an app server (custom implementation requirement, I'm using a simple REST API). However, all the logic to connect to the app server is contained within the `IntentService`.

To associate the device token with a logged in user I assume I have two options:

- a) Somehow inject the user information into the `IntentService`.
- b) Have the `IntentService` emit a custom event in the `OnHandleIntent` handler to which my application can respond.

Since I would like to implement push notifications for both Android and iOS, ideally 'b' would be the best option since I can create a better abstraction but I guess either solution would be workable for the moment.

Given these options, what would be a good strategy to associate the device token with the currently logged in user?

[1] https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android

Answer (score 0):

It´s not just the associating part. Your server must be able to send push notifications to google gcm and apple apn. I´m wondering if you already covered that part. Doing so manually would be a pain. If you are using .NET in the server side, check out this [library](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp). Here´s another for [python/django](https://github.com/jleclanche/django-push-notifications)

The association part can be done easily in a web api controller. Basically you need:

1. A table (1 to many) for device registrations: user id foreign key + registration
   id/token
2. Create a controller POST method to save user id (with fk to actual user) + registration id/token to the previous table
3. Once the user logs in your app, run all the gmc/apn registration
   process.
4. Once you get your registration id/token, send it to the controller

In fact, there are many other details to be implemented, like:

1. What happens if you get 2/3 different registration ids for the same user?
2. You should provide another REST method to unregister, and call it
   for example when the user logs out in the mobile app.
3. Etc...

There are some libs taking care of all this. I suggest you take a look and pick one.

**EDIT**

Another option would be to subscribe to another tag that would be exactly the user id "topics/id"

Comment: Only interested at the user/token association part. I've got the server side logic working and it's pushing notifications just fine. The problem is that it's "broadcasting" to all apps subscribed to "/topics/global". To be able to send a push to a specific user I need to associate the device token with a user.

Comment: Re. your edit. Yes, I can create a "topic" for a specific user using the device token, but again, how does the server know which "topics/id" to send a notification to? I think you're focusing to much on notifications, the question is more a C# question than a notification question, i.e. inject something into an `Intent` or have the `Intent` emit an event. Hope this make sense..

Comment: Because that id in the topics/id should be the same user id you save on the server database

Comment: I understand that but I currently have no way to "associate" the device token with a user. In the `IntentSevice` I have the device token but no user information. So, when I have a device token in the `IntentService` how do I tell the app server with which user to "associate" the device token? I either need to get the user information INTO the `IntentService` or I need to get the device token OUT OF the `IntentService`. With just a device token I cannot do anything other than broadcasting notifications.

Comment: Yeah, to do that, obviously you need the user info first. Why can´t you delay the device registration until the user logs in? Many examples do registration on MainActivity but you can actually do that whenever or wherever you need to. Or if you prefer, you can save the token to a local cache and send it to server once the user logs in

Comment: The user is logged in. I have the user info. The question is, how do I get the user info and the device token in the same place? To obtain a device token you need an `IntentService` since it's an async process and the device token can change at any time, the `IntentService` listens for this change. So, I either need to bring the user info INTO the `IntentService` or somehow retrieve the device token OUT OF the `IntentService`.

Comment: Saving it to local settings cache?

Answer (score 0):

you need to send unique android_id with url ,something like ,
where regid is token u get ,

which u will get from : 
android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

```
 String url = "https://push.monitoring.computer/api/notification/device/register/" + "1/" + regid + "/android/" + android_id;

        try {

            URL url1 = new URL(url);
            URLConnection uc = url1.openConnection();

            String basicAuth = Base64.encodeToString((APIKEY).getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);

            uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
            InputStream in = uc.getInputStream();

            // Log.e(TAG, "response: " + response);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        },
```

This is java code which can easily translated to c#

Comment: Understood. But, the question is about getting the user Id and the push token in the same place. Not how to send push notifications. Hope that makes sense..